# Store keyword from Pig in Hbase?

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, store, keyword

I want to store a Dataset from Pig into HBase. How can I use the word all ( which is also a keyword in Pig) for a qualifier in HBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
as (all:chararray)
```